# How to install scandir in python script package

Tags: python, scandir

How to install **scandir** in `python` `package` because I failed to install .

This is my error:

```
error: could not create 'c:\program files\python35\Lib\site-packages\scandir.py': Permission denied
```

Anyone can share me idea on doing the installation?

Comment: it seems that your windows account doesn't have the permission for the folder.

Comment: Try using sudo. Then it will get the permissions it needs. Before the terminal command, use `sudo `

Comment: I using window, so I I going to solve that?

Comment: Use elevation. Start a command prompt as an administrator and then attempt the installation.